# Iterative loop equivalent in FileMaker script?

Tags: database, scripting, filemaker

I'm new to FileMaker Pro scripts and I'm wondering if there's an equivalent to an iterative loop. (i.e. like for loop in C/C++/Java). If so anyone have any examples I could look at. (I'm using FMP 11 if that helps).

Algorithm: I currently have a database where I'm looking to iterate through all the records in the database and check two specific columns in each record and if they contain a specific number and then increment a counter. Then move to the next record.

thanks!

Comment: "*check two specific columns in each record and if they contain a specific number*" Couldn't you **find** these records to begin with? Finding is (in most cases) fast. Looping is not.

Answer (score 2):

A basic loop structure in a FileMaker script would look like this:

```
# Start with a found set of the records you want to investigate (or all records)
#
# Set the counter variable
#
Set Variable [$counter ; Value:0]
#
# Go to the first record
#
Go to Record/Request/Page [First]
#
# Loop until you reach the last record, incrementing counter if appropriate
#
Loop
   If [ table::value = desiredValue ]
      Set Variable [$counter ; Value:$counter + 1]
   End If
   Go to Record/Request/Page [Next ; Exit after last]
End Loop
```

However, this is usually a pretty slow method to query all of your data. There are a number of ways that may be more appropriate. Taking your example, and assuming you are looking for static values in your data, you might do something like this:

```
# Assume we are looking for field1 = value1 and field2 = value2
# 
Enter Find Mode []
Set Field [ Table::field1 ; value1 ]
Set Field [ Table::field2 ; value2 ]
Perform Find []
#
# We have now found all records where field1 = value1 and field2 = value2
# We simply set $counter to the count of found records
#
Set Variable [ $counter ; Value:Get ( FoundCount ) ]
```

Comment: Great thanks! Makes sense. It's a pretty small database but I want it to be designed where it could be scalable for larger projects. Thanks for documenting it so well too